# Yeoman generator-webapp prints the inner text of scripts and title nodes inside the window

Tags: html, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, livereload

I scaffolded a project using the YEOMAN generator-webapp (I'm running Nodejs v4.0.0, NPM 3.5.3, Bower 1.7.5, Yeoman 1.6.0). When i ran the `grunt serve` command everything fired up just fine. All scripts and styles got loaded without errors.

## The Issue

For some reason i just can't get my head around the following issue. All browsers i have tested (chrome 47, safari 9.0.3 and mozilla 43.0.2) are showing the value of the`<title></title>` and `<script></script>` nodes as text inside the window.

[image: Screenshot of window, source and console.]

The strange part is, the scripts do got executed, as seen in te console.

At first i thought it may be a LiveReload or BrowserSync problem. But even after running `grunt build` and serving `/dist/` using `http-server` the error remains.

I also reinstalled the complete project after updating NPM and Bower. After running `grunt serve` again the problem seemed to be gone. However, after a couple of changes in the index.html file the problem reoccured. Even after returning the index.html in it's original state.

Unfortunately i couldn't find any good reading material that even talks about this issue. (this is the closest i got; https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/791. I'm not sure which steps to take from here. I includes the gruntfile.js, package.json and index.html. A little help or a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

### gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2016-01-27 using
// generator-webapp 1.1.2
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// If you want to recursively match all subfolders, use:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
  });

  // Configurable paths
  var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      babel: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:dist']
      },
      babelTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['babel:test', 'test:watch']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      sass: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'postcss']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'postcss']
      }
    },

    browserSync: {
      options: {
        notify: true,
        background: true,
        watchOptions: {
          ignored: ''
        }
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          files: [
            '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*',
            '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
          ],
          port: 9000,
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          open: false,
          logLevel: 'silent',
          host: 'localhost',
          server: {
            baseDir: ['.tmp', './test', config.app],
            routes: {
              '/bower_components': './bower_components'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          background: false,
          server: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= config.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    eslint: {
      target: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
        'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://<%= browserSync.test.options.host %>:<%= browserSync.test.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },

    // Compiles ES6 with Babel
    babel: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        presets: ['es2015']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapEmbed: true,
        sourceMapContents: true,
        includePaths: ['.']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
          src: ['*.{scss,sass}'],
          dest: '.tmp/styles',
          ext: '.css'
        }]
      }
    },

    postcss: {
      options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
          // Add vendor prefixed styles
          require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']
          })
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
          '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= config.dist %>',
          '<%= config.dist %>/images',
          '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      },
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        },{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
          src: '*.{ico,png}',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true,
          // true would impact styles with attribute selectors
          removeRedundantAttributes: false,
          useShortDoctype: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: '{,*/}*.html',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
          dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.txt',
            'images/{,*/}*.webp',
            '{,*/}*.html',
            'fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }]
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'babel:dist',
        'sass'
      ],
      test: [
        'babel'
      ],
      dist: [
        'babel',
        'sass',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', function (target) {

    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'browserSync:dist']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss',
      'browserSync:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
      grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:test',
        'postcss'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'browserSync:test',
      'mocha'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:eslint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-browser-sync": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-eslint": "^17.0.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.2.0",
    "grunt-mocha": "^0.4.12",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "browser": true,
      "es6": true,
      "jquery": true,
      "mocha": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ],
      "indent": [
        2,
        2
      ]
    }
  },
  "name": "Test_application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    <!-- Test script -->
    <script>//<![CDATA[
      var test = 'Well, this is not helping.';
      console.log(test);
    //]]></script>

    <script>
      var test = 'Wow, i have been executed! Why am i visible as text in the window?';
      console.log(test);
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->



    <!-- build:js(.tmp) scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i still don't know which problem exactly causes the effects like described above. However, i did found a solution. It seem's the Yeomean [generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) module hasn't been maintained for a while and lost some stability. (The Yeomen crew is currently looking for maintainers)

They did released a Gulp edition of the webapp generator, [which could be found here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp). I simply build a new project with the gulp generator and replaced the new app directory with the old one. Worked like a charm. Don't forget to [install Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) global first if you didn't already.